# Can I use one European work permit to work in another European country?

Tags: visa

Is it possible to get a work visa from a European country and then quit the job and start to work with another company in another country?

Comment: Probably not - and even if so, it would depend on the specifics of the visa itself. Many work visas are tied to the specific job it is issued for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this answer I will assume that "work visa from a European country" mean a visa issued by particular country allowing work in said country.
The answer is **NO**. 
Each country has it's own visa policies and visa issued by one is valid only in the country of origin. The name Europe Employment Visa can be misleading but there is no Schengen work visa.

Comment: Just to add: The free movement of workforce only applies if you are a citizen of an EU country - it might include non-EU countries in Europe (Switzerland, Norway, etc) by agreement, not sure (the Nordic countries had free movement far before EU). Then you can freely move around in the EU and start working in another country with just some paperwork formalities to register in that country. It does not apply to immigrants with a working visa, as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Moreover, some visas are not only attached to a specific country, but to a specific company. So, even if you move to another company inside the same neighbourhood, you have to do a lot of paperwork. The german work visa (Arbeitvisum) is an example.